# Запятая вместо тире в БСП с противопоставлением

Tags: запятые, тире, бсп

*Повышение в должности — это не вопрос результативности(,) это вопрос ответственности и компетентности.*

Во избежание двух тире можно ли поставить запятую, несмотря на противопоставление без использования союза? Я понимаю, что вместо «это» можно поставить союз «а» и дело в шляпе, но хочется оставить конструкцию в таком виде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Повышение в дОлжности — это не вопрос результатИвности, это вопрос отвЕтственности и компетЕнтности.**

Такое предложение возможно.

1) Предложения со связкой ***ЭТО*** можно рассматривать как **вариант предложений с именительным темы**, когда тема задается существительным (инфинитивом), далее ставится тире, а местоимение ЭТО замещает именительный темы, фактически становится подлежащим, но считается связкой.

Например: Признать свои ошибки – **на это** он не способен. Это предложение с именительным темы, причем местоимение является не подлежащим, а дополнением, и тогда связкой его уже не назовешь.

2) **Структуру заданного предложения можно рассматривать именно так:** именительный темы, дальше тире, а потом однородная конструкция с противопоставлением, при этом вторая ее часть распространяет первую, а союз А подразумевается.

Интонация  **распространительная**, то есть понижение тона после первой части, далее небольшая пауза, а затем   вторая часть со своей собственной интонацией.

Comment: Что вы, кстати, имеете в виду под «распространяет»? Распространяют конструкцию вроде второстепенные члены, а не однородные.

Answer (score 2):

**Повышение в должности — это не вопрос результативности, это вопрос ответственности и компетентности.**

Вариант с запятой — самый естественный, есть немало подобных примеров в Нацкорпусе.

> Возвращение более чем 200 тысяч "зелёных фуражек" в родное гэбэшное лоно ― это не восстановление памятника Железному Феликсу, это будет посерьёзнее. [Александр Гольц. Кремлевский звездопад (2003) // «Еженедельный журнал», 2003.03.17]
>
> ― Вывезенные капиталы ― это не наличные, лежащие в каком-то укромном местечке, это депозиты в банках, ценные бумаги, недвижимость, а то и приобретённое за эти деньги производство. [Светлана Сухова. Мы можем просчитать вас полностью (2003) // «Итоги», 2003.01.13]

В качестве альтернативы, помимо варианта с союзом *а*, можно предложить такое построение:

**Повышение в должности — это не вопрос результативности, повышение в должности — это вопрос ответственности и компетентности.**